# Broke CSS - When upload wordpress from local to hosting (what is inside .htaccess)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I upload `WordPress` from local to free hosting, but when I access my website, `CSS` was gone.

And I can't access `wp-admin`: `https://fuukaa.000webhostapp.com/`. When I access `wp-admin` so my `URL` move to localhost.

I use theme Avada, I think Avada didn't use.
I changed file `wp.config`follow my information setting host. Inside my `.htaccess` have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But it not work. Is my `.htaccess` wrong?

**UPDATE HOW TO FIX THE ERROR**

I open file `function.php` in my theme folder (I use theme Avada) and write inside 2 line code :

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

So my css, my theme are working now. Thank you all

Comment: No, it seems you haven't updated the URL of your site in the database. Check on Google, there are plenty of tutorials on "migrating WordPress to external server" that can guide you with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you haven't changed your siteurl in the database. You need to change that to the live url. Follow the steps below:

[PhpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuJ9K.png)

1. Open phpMyAdmin on your live server
2. Click your database in the left sidebar to load the tables
3. Click on your wp_options table
4. Find and edit the 'siteurl' and 'home' rows (Click the pencil icon to edit).
5. Finally, click the "Go" button to save your changes.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your default siteurl is not changed into database.

Open your database/PHPMyadmin and go to wp_options table. Look for the siteurl and homeurl in the database and changed its value with your site's url.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your .htaccess. I think your css file is missing or broken.